# Error: module 'MSGARCH' has no attribute 'predict'

Tags: python, r, rpy2

I am using the package rpy2 to use R language in Python environment. I am using the MSGARCH package which is only on R. The package is clearly suppose to come with the attribute predict.
https://rdrr.io/cran/MSGARCH/man/predict.html
 I don't understand why I have this error. Do you have an idea please?

the full error message is :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "markov.py", line 165, in <module>
    pred = ms.predict(object = fitMCMC, newdata = None, nahead = '30L')
AttributeError: module 'MSGARCH' has no attribute 'predict'
```

The code is:

```
ms = importr('MSGARCH')
from rpy2.robjects import r, pandas2ri, numpy2ri, vectors
pandas2ri.activate()
numpy2ri.activate()
base = importr('base')
stats = importr('stats')

pred = ms.predict(object = fitMCMC, newdata = None, nahead = '30L')
```

Comment: Edit the question to include the full error traceback message.

Comment: sure, i did itt

Comment: After the `ms = importr('MSGARCH')` line, can you insert the line `print (ms.__file__)` and show us the output?

Comment: I have print (ms.predict) with output : module 'MSGARCH' has no attribute 'predict'

Comment: Well, we know that, because of the original error.  Please show us the output of `print (ms.__file__)`

Comment: I see. I tried print (ms.__file__) with output: AttributeError: module 'MSGARCH' has no attribute '__file__'

Comment: Hmm.  `importr` must do things differently than a regular import.  Which makes sense, otherwise you could just use a regular import!  Do you have a python file in the local directory, named `MSGARCH.py` or `msgarch.py`?

Comment: there is a file named garch.py in the local directory. Yes I could do 'from MSGARCH import predict' if this was a python package but it is R package. Is there any way to import with similar method in R?

Comment: That module link shows r code, not python code.  Where did you copy this python code from?

Comment: I did not copy this code. I wrote it with the help of the module rpy2 which allows using R in python environment.

Comment: Got it. the correct way to write it was : pred = ms.predict_MSGARCH_MCMC_FIT(object = fitMCMC, newdata = None, nahead = '30L').   The documents are not very explicit...